# How long can my data stay on Ubuntu One

Tags: server

How long can my data stay on Ubuntu One? Even if I do not use them? Could happend to me, that I do not use my data for a long time, that I lose them?
Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data will stay on Ubuntu One forever, even if you dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't delete your account on ubuntu one, you will be able to access them.

The only reason that can cause your data to be deleted on ubuntu one is a huge failure on their side or if ubuntu one no longer exist...